# MS SQL Query assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a bit of a newbie. For all of my research I am having trouble finding the correct solution.

I'm trying to generate multiple reports from SQL, my query looks like this:

```
declare @startdate datetime = '2013-05-01'
declare @enddate datetime = '2014-04-30'

select DISTINCT (customer_name) as CUSTOMER,total_price as REVENUE,
       work_order_no as WORKORDER 
from work_order_tb 
where last_update BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate 
      AND status='Delivered' order by customer_name
```

This outputs something like this:

```
CUSTOMER     REVENUE  Work Order

contoso inc.    46000   1747
contoso inc.    5120    2794
contoso inc.    10240   3669
wall world inc. 133600  0157
wall world inc. 92040   9402
wall world inc. 38400   3248
wall world inc. 133400  2559
bugerplace      5120    7455
burgerplace     2785    1211
```

I'm trying to get it to return a single unique customer name from that column so I can sum all of the revenue and display it by customer so that it looks like:

```
CUSTOMER    REVENUE WORK Order
contoso inc.    61360   174,727,943,669
wall world inc. 397440  157,940,232,482,559
bugerplace      7905    74,551,211
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look up aggregates, specifically SUM.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title is more descriptive of the actual problem. Your tag informs us that it's MS SQL (sql-server), and we know you need assistance because you posted here, so you've provided no relevant information in your title. The title should describe the actual problem or question being asked, and should be something meaningful if it's later displayed in a search result.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!I did have an iteration where I used Sum, but I couldn't figure out how to "aggregate" the names. Thanks for that I will look that up.

Comment: Ugh I missed the bit about the comma separated list of WorkOrders. You need to do this in a couple phases since it is new. First get total per customer, then worry about the list of WorkOrders. Do you really to list all the work orders like that? Sort of goes against the concept of summary data.

Comment: Sorry to barrage you with comments but it also looks like your tables are serious need of normalization. You should not store the customer name in the work order table. It should live only in the customers table with a foreign key in the work orders table. Consider how much hassle it would be if a customer changed their name.

Comment: Quick aside, you may want to be careful with your `@enddate` variable. Since it's a datetime, if the data can ever be inserted with a time (and it will find a way), you'll lose those rows if their date is the same as the end date (e.g., '2014-04-30T08:00:00' wouldn't show in the above query).

Comment: I did try to edit the question but it is giving me some sort of error when I submit the changes. I'll keep trying. Thanks again everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, Aggregate SUM and [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).

Assuming that work_order is as int type column of table

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f02f9/6)

```
SELECT 
      t.CUSTOMER, 
      SUM(t.REVENUE) as REVENUE,
      STUFF(
              (
                 SELECT ',' + Cast(s.work_order as varchar)
                 FROM tblname s
                 WHERE s.CUSTOMER = t.CUSTOMER
                 FOR XML PATH('')
               ),1,1,''
            ) AS [WORK Order]
FROM tblname t
Group BY CUSTOMER
```

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and advice. I learned quite a bit more than I ever knew going in. This answer did exactly what I was looking for, I think I can modify this to meet all of my needs although I will need to study it a bit so I can understand exactly what it did and why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.Customer,
sum(b.Revenue),
STUFF((select ','+WORKOrder AS WO from work_order_tb a where a.Customer=b.Customer for XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
from work_order_tb b 
group by Customer
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, not a problem; there are worse issues to have than barrages of help :) I realized that aggregation wasn't working because of the work order numbers (when I did some research based on Ken White's advice. I used grouping to aggregate the customer names, and sum of course to get my totals.

Comment: Yes I agree this wasn't very well designed, the accountants want to audit data from various departments so they can cross-reference for accuracy. this is why the data such as customer name may live in a few different tables currently.

Comment: Let me give your suggestion a try as well.